# Change log_error_verbosity to 4

Tags: error-handling, google-cloud-sql

I cannot change the log_error_verbosity using mysql workbench. 
set global log_error_verbosity = 4;
Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

I can login as the root user with mysql workbench, but I cannot give that user the super privilege to change this setting.

It is not listed in the configuration options on the google cloud sql admin panel.
Does anyone know how to do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because Cloud SQL is a managed service and to ensure its operation, [it's not possible to grant users super privileges](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/users#superuser_restrictions).

There's an open [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/74357883) to allow users to have super privileges on their instances.

In Cloud SQL, MySQL error logs are actually enabled by default. If you go to the `Cloud Console > SQL > Instance` page, you can find the "View MySQL error logs" button on the bottom right. This will take you to Stackdriver Logging, in which you can view logs with the property `logName: "projects/[PROJECT_NAME]/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fmysql.err"`, i.e. the mysql error logs. You can also verify that info, warning, and error messages will be shown, and you can filter these with the appropriate Stackdriver filters.

Comment: Right, by default it was set to 3. I need more info and want it set to 4. Having super privileges would be great. At the least, giving more to choose from in the configuration options seems like a minimal fix. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: as a next step you can open a feature request to add the possibility to modify this flag

https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=1162714